# Which is exact dating of modern Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra

Tags: astrology, parashara

According to [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11758/was-rishi-vyasa-the-great-grandson-of-rishi-vashishtha) Rishi Parashara (who wrote the Jyotisha text Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra) who was the father of Rishi Vyasa (who wrote the Mahabharata).

but as per the Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra's wikipage,

> J. Gonda states that at 'some time after 600 [C.E.] was written the
> purva-khanda of what was to become known as the Brhatparasarahora
> [Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra], ascribed to Parasa... [it] is deeply
> indebted to the [Brhajjataka of Varahamihira]; it has also borrowed
> two verses from Sphujidhvaja... and its existence is presupposed by
> the author of the uttara-khanda, which was commented on by
> Govindasvamin in ca. 850 [C.E.]. Therefore, the purva-khanda must have
> been written between ca. 600 and 750... but before 800'

So this shows ranges of ~600-800 CE.

Can any other proof exists regarding dating of Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra ?